# Template not binding to observable while using async pipe on initial load

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, contentful

I'm using the [contentful](https://contentful.github.io/contentful.js/contentful/3.8.0/ContentfulClientAPI.html) js SDK to fetch data in a **service**. The SDK provides a method to retrieve entries from a promise and also parse those entries. Since I would like to use observables, I am returning the promise as an observable and then transforming from there.

In my **home** component, I am then calling the **contentfulService** OnInit and unwrapping the observable in the template using the **async** pipe.

My problem:
When the home component loads, the template is not there even though the service has fetched the data successfully. Now, if I interact with the DOM (click, hover) on the page, the template will instantly appear. Why is this not just loading asynchronously on page load? How can I fix this?

[An example .gif showing the behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUW4A.gif)

**contentful.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';    
import { Service } from '../models/service.model';
import * as contentful from 'contentful';


@Injectable()
export class ContentfulService {

  client: any;

  services: Service[];
  service: Service;    

  constructor() {    
    this.client = contentful.createClient({
      space: SPACE_ID,
      accessToken: API_KEY
    });
  }   


  loadServiceEntries(): Observable<Service[]> {

    let contentType = 'service';
    let selectParams = 'fields';

    return this.getEntriesByContentType(contentType, selectParams)
      .take(1)          
      .map(entries => {
        this.services = [];

        let parsedEntries = this.parseEntries(entries);

        parsedEntries.items.forEach(entry => {
          this.service = entry.fields;
          this.services.push(this.service);
        });

        this.sortAlpha(this.services, 'serviceTitle');
        return this.services;
      })          
      .publishReplay(1)
      .refCount();

  }


  parseEntries(data) {
    return this.client.parseEntries(data);
  }


  getEntriesByContentType(contentType, selectParam) {

    const subject = new Subject();

    this.client.getEntries({
      'content_type': contentType,
      'select': selectParam
    })
      .then(
      data => {
        subject.next(data);
        subject.complete();
      },
      err => {
        subject.error(err);
        subject.complete();
      }
      );

    return subject.asObservable();
  }


  sortAlpha(objArray: Array<any>, property: string) {
    objArray.sort(function (a, b) {
      let textA = a[property].toUpperCase();
      let textB = b[property].toUpperCase();

      return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
  }


}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ContentfulService } from '../shared/services/contentful.service';
import { Service } from '../shared/models/service.model';    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  service: Service;      
  services: Service[];
  services$: Observable<Service[]>;

  constructor(
    private contentfulService: ContentfulService,
  ) {

  }    

  ngOnInit() {       

    this.services$ = this.contentfulService.loadServiceEntries();

    this.services$.subscribe(
      () => console.log('services loaded'),
      console.error
    );    

  }; 


}
```

**home.component.html**

```
...
<section class="bg-faded">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-4" *ngFor="let service of services$ | async">
          <div class="card card-inverse text-center">
            <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" [src]="service?.serviceImage?.fields?.file?.url | safeUrl">
            <div class="card-block">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{service?.serviceTitle}}</h4>
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item bg-brand-black"><i class="fa fa-wrench mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Cras justo odio</li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-brand-black"><i class="fa fa-wrench mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-brand-black"><i class="fa fa-wrench mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vestibulum at eros</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-brand-red">Learn More</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the Contentful promise is resolving outside of Angular's zone.

You can ensure the the observable's methods are run inside the zone by injecting `NgZone` into your service:

```
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  this.client = contentful.createClient({
    space: SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: API_KEY
  });
}
```

And by calling using the injected zone's `run` when calling the subject's methods:

```
getEntriesByContentType(contentType, selectParam) {

  const subject = new Subject();

  this.client.getEntries({
    'content_type': contentType,
    'select': selectParam
  })
  .then(
    data => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        subject.next(data);
        subject.complete();
      });
    },
    err => {
      this.zone.run(() => {
        subject.error(err);
        subject.complete();
      });
    }
  );

  return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @cartant, this was most definitely the problem.  I thought it would end up being something simple...I didn't know the use case for `NgZone`.